# Absolute minimum and maximum of $f(x,y,z)=x^4+y^4+z^4-4xyz$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

I have to find the absolute maximum and minimum of the function $f(x,y,z)=x^4+y^4+z^4-4xyz$ over $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 9$, $x,y,z\geq 0$.

I'm having problems to find the constrained extremas in $x^2+y^2+z^2=9$. I have tried by using the Lagrange's Multipliers theorem, by parametrizing the sphere and by algebraic manipulating the function but I haven't been able to come up with the solution.

Could anybody help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Introduce the dummy variable $w$. Then we want to minimize
$$
F(x,y,z,w)=x^4+y^4+z^4+w^4-1-4xyzw
$$subject to $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 9, w=1$. By AM-GM
$$
(x^4+y^4+z^4+w^4)\geq4 \sqrt[4]{x^4y^4z^4w^4}=4xyzw,
$$with equality iff $x=y=z=w$. Then since we must have $w=1$, the minimum occurs at $(x,y,z)=(1,1,1)$, giving $f(1,1,1)=-1$.

Now for the maximum. Note that
$$
f(x,y,z) = \langle x^2,y^2,z^2\rangle \cdot \langle x^2,y^2,z^2\rangle-4xyz
$$By Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$
|f(x,y,z)|\leq (9)^2-4xyz;
$$equality occurs if any of the variables are $0$. At $(3,0,0)$ we have $f(3,0,0)=81$ and at $(3/\sqrt{2},3/\sqrt{2},0)$, we have $f(3/\sqrt{2},3/\sqrt{2},0)=81/2$.

Comment: Why does a maximum occur at $(3, 0, 0)$?

Comment: @JoseRamirez does that answer your question?

Comment: Not quite, since in this case, it's not obvious to me that one of the variables has to be zero (the condition for equality has to go both ways here). Also, why did you add a new variable to try to minimize $f$? You could have just tried to minimize $f(x,y,z) + 1$ with the same argument, and get the same result

Comment: If you buy that $|f|\leq 81-\text{thing}$, with $\text{thing}\geq 0$, clearly having one or two variables equal to zero is the best possible situation. Sometimes it's easier to deal with a slightly more general object. That's what I did here, as it allowed me to use the AMGM inequality.

Comment: Sometimes it's easier, but here it seems that it made the argument a bit more clunky, since you add it to create a new function, and then say that $w = 1$; why put it in the first place? And, if I understood correctly, you're just saying that equality is attained when you set some variable equal to 0, right? The theorems you use have nothing to do with your claim, right?

Comment: Compare with the usual way, I hardly think it's more clunky...

Comment: What 'usual way'? If by usual way you mean saying that $x^4 + y^4 + z^4 + 1 \ge 4xyz$ directly by AM-GM, I just proved the same thing without adding another variable. Anyway, I just wanted to understand your 'why' in that case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108257/discussion-between-integrand-and-jose-ramirez).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more routine answer. First, to find critical points in the interior, compute the gradient:
$$
\nabla f = (4x^3-4yz,4y^3-4xz,4z^3-4xy)
$$Certainly the origin is a critical point, and if any of the variables equal zero, the other two do as well. Otherwise, we have
$$
\begin{cases}
x^3-yz &=0\\
y^3-xz &=0\\
z^3-xy &=0\\
\end{cases}
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
x^4 &=xyz\\
y^4 &= xyz\\
z^4 &=xyz\\
\end{cases}
$$Since we are assuming all variables are now positive, this only admits the symmetric solution (because $x^4=y^4$ so we can infer $x=y$ and so on).

Now along the boundary. Let $f$ be the objective function and $g$ the constraint.  No harm in substituting $\lambda\mapsto 2\lambda$ to simplify the arithmetic:
$$
\begin{cases}
4x^3-4yz &=4\lambda x\\
4y^3-4xz &=4\lambda y\\
4z^3-4xy &=4\lambda z\\
\end{cases}
$$Do the same symmetry trick as before:
$$
\begin{cases}
x^4-\lambda x^2 &= xyz\\
y^4-\lambda y^2 &= xyz\\
z^4-\lambda z^2 &= xyz\\
\end{cases}
$$First, suppose $z=0$. Then either we have $(x,y)=(0,0)$, $(x,y)=(\sqrt{\lambda},0)$, or $(\sqrt{\lambda},\sqrt{\lambda})$; with $x^2+y^2+z^2=9$, these reduce to $(x,y)=(3,0)$ or $(3/\sqrt{2},3/\sqrt{2})$ (this holds up to permutation). If $xyz\neq 0$, to be quite honest, I used a computer algebra system because the equations become horrific. I couldn't find any other solutions where all variables were positive.

All that remains is to check our candidate points.

- $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$. $f(0,0,0)=0$
- $(x,y,z)=(x,x,x)$. $f(x,x,x)=3x^4-4x^3,$ $0\leq x\leq \sqrt{3}$; this has a minimum at $x=1$, corresponding to $f(1,1,1)=-1$, and a maximum of $27-12\sqrt{3}$ at $x=\sqrt{3}$
- $(x,y,z)=(3,0,0)$. $f(3,0,0)=81$.
- $(x,y,z)=(3/\sqrt{2},3/\sqrt{2},0)$. $f(3/\sqrt{2},3/\sqrt{2},0)=81/2$.

In conclusion, $f$ has a maximum at $(3,0,0)$ (cyclic) and a minimum at $(1,1,1$).

Comment: The equations are $$\begin{cases}x^4-\lambda x^2=xyz\\ y^4-\lambda y^2=xyz\\ z^4-\lambda z^2=xyz\end{cases},$$ aren't they?

Answer (score 0):

**Integrand's** concern about the case for $ \ xyz \ \ne \ 0 \ $ turns out to be unnecessary.  If we solve the original Lagrange equations for $ \ \lambda \ $ , we obtain

$$ \left\{ \begin{array}{c}
2·(x^3-yz)  \ = \ \lambda x \\ 2·(y^3-4xz)  \ = \ \lambda y \\
2·(z^3- xy) \ = \ \lambda z
\end{array} \right. \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \lambda \  =  \ \frac{2·(x^3-yz)}{x} \ =  \ \frac{2·(y^3-xz)}{y} \ =  \ \frac{2·(z^3-xy)}{z} \ \ . $$

Cross-multiplying the first ratio-pair produces

$$ x^3y \ - \  y^2z \ \ = \ \ xy^3  -  x^2z \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x^2z \ -  \ y^2z \ \ = \ \ xy^3 - x^3y $$ $$ \Rightarrow \ \ z·(x^2-y^2) \ \ = \ \ xy·(y^2 - x^2) \ \ \Rightarrow \ \  (z \ + \ xy) \ · \ (x^2-y^2) \ \ = \ \ 0  \ \ ;   $$

similarly, we have from the other ratio-pairs,
$$ (y \ + \ xz) \ · \ (x^2-z^2) \ \ = \ \ 0  \ \ \ , \ \ \ (x \ + \ yz) \ · \ (y^2-z^2) \ \ = \ \ 0  \ \ .   $$

[That each of these equations looks like a "cyclic-permutation" re-labeling of the others is due to the same symmetry being found in the expression for $ \ f(x,y,z) \ $ and the symmetry of the spherical constraint.]

The "difference-of-squares" factors would tell us such things as $ \ y = \pm x \ , $ but since we are also restricted to the first octant, we have just $ \ x = y = z \ $ as one case.  This gives the $ \ f(x,x,x) \ = \ 3x^4 - 4x^3 \ $ results.

The remaining case comes from the factors such as $ \ z + xy \ = \ 0 \ \Rightarrow \  z \ = \ -xy \ . $  Again because we are in the first octant, including those portions of the coordinate planes, this requires that $ \ z = 0 \ $ and either $ \ x = 0 \ \ \text{or} \ \ y=0 \ . $  Together with the related results from the other two equations, we obtain the three critical points which are the permutations of $ \ (3 \ , \ 0 \ , \ 0 ) \ $  and the three permutations of $ \ (3\sqrt{2} \ , \ 3\sqrt{2} \ , \ 0 ) \ . $  So it does not appear that any critical points have been overlooked and the conclusion in **Integrand's** 19 May post is confirmed.

(Incidentally, the origin is a rather interesting saddle point.  The function $ \ f(x,x,x) \ = \ 3x^4 - 4x^3 \ $ has an inflection point at $ \ x = 0 \ $ , so this change in concavity occurs along each of the lines passing between opposing octants:
$$ -x = -y = -z \ \rightarrow \ x = y = z \ \ , \ \ x = -y = -z \ \rightarrow \ -x  = y = z \ \ , $$
$$ -x = y = -z \ \rightarrow \ x = -y = z \ \ \text{and} \ \ -x = -y = z \ \rightarrow \ x  = y = -z \ \ . ) $$